# Rare error about missing view welcome/index (:formats=>["image/*"])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a Heroku / Rails 3.2 site with a homepage at welcome/index. Everything works fine, and the homepage gets plenty of hits, but every once in a rare while, I'll notice one of these errors in my logs:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template welcome/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["image/*"], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views" * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/`... (it lists a few more gem locations where it looked)

The welcome view is in the normal place, `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`. The `formats=image/*` is suspicious to me, and I can cause a similar error if I request `...com/welcome.jpg`, but the logs are reporting these errors as being a request for the root /.

What is going on? How can I prevent it? (How can I replicate it?).

**Resolution:**
Use `respond_to :html` in the controller, [as shown in the accepted answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495326/rare-error-about-missing-view-welcome-index-formats-image/27495474#27495474).

**Explanation:**
My app was attempting to respond to every type of request, (html, jpg, json, rss, etc). The fix was to respond to html requests only, and send 406 errors to non-html requests.  I could replicate these errors by requesting urls like `...com/welcome.rss`, or by entering this in Chrome console:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","",false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "image/*");
xmlhttp.send();
```

The results of the fix are:
 - The user will get a 406 instead of a 500
 - My app won't have to deal with 500s
 - Most importantly, I'll get less errors in my logs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `respond_with` in your action to avoid this error.

For example, in users_contoller:

```
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)
  end
```

If there is a request of /users.jpg, it will return **406 Not Acceptable**.

Comment: My welcome#index is almost empty. Could the (redundant?) `render` be causing a problem?
`def index
  render :index
end`

Comment: Yes. You can just add `respond_with`, I forgot that, you need to add `respond_to :html` in you controller. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, so my `render :index` was necessary, which meant when using respond_to, I needed to use `respond_to (), template: 'welcome/index'`.  Thanks for your help.